# Rails Active Admin: Why isn't my custom form rendering any inputs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic

**Rails 3.1.1

Active Admin 0.4.4

formtastic 2.1.1**

**This is the active admin controller for my `Agency` model.**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Agency do
  form do |f|
    f.input :name
    f.input :contact_email, :label=>"Email invoices to"
    f.input :api_key, :hint=>"Create a key by following <a href=\"#\" target=\"_blank\">these instructions</a>".html_safe
    f.actions
  end
end
```

**The form should render the three inputs, followed by the submit button, but all I get is:**

[image: no inputs]

**Just to be clear, the HTML shows no signs of the missing inputs:**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/agencies" class="formtastic agency" id="agency_new" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" name="agency_new">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="...">
  </div>
  <fieldset class="actions">
    <ol>
      <li class="action input_action" id="agency_submit_action">
        <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Agency">
      </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**I also tried using fieldsets, with the same (faulty) output:**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Agency do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "New Agency" do 
      f.input :name
      f.input :contact_email, :label=>"Email invoices to"
      f.input :api_key, :hint=>"Create a key by following <a href=\"#\" target=\"_blank\">these instructions</a>".html_safe
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

**Update: I've discovered that commenting out the `f.actions` line gets formtastic to actually print the inputs, but now just without the button.**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Agency do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "New Agecny" do 
      f.input :name
      f.input :contact_email, :label=>"Email invoices to"
      f.input :api_key, :hint=>"Create a key by following <a href=\"#\" target=\"_blank\">these instructions</a>".html_safe
    end

    #f.actions
  end
end
```

Form with inputs but no button:

[image: no button]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using this: `f.buttons :submit`

I also think that the block for buttons/actions changed a bit in a version of active admin at some point, so you may be tripped up by old tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`f.buttons` should be used, rather than `f.actions`.

`f.buttons`, prints the buttons. `f.actions` expects a block for formatting the buttons, similar to `f.inputs`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right on track: wrap your inputs in an f.inputs block.

Uncomment the line "f.actions" outside the block.

You should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this: f.input :type => :submit  .This worked for me

```
form do |f| 
  f.input :starts_at
  f.input :ends_at
  f.input :type => :submit
end
```